# Vertical Histogram in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to put text in to a vertical histogram using the length of words and the frequency of those lengths as variables. I can do it easily horizontally, but I'm totally lost when it comes to going vertical. (yes, new to Python and programming in general)

**I only want to use built-in modules for Python 3**

Here's what I have so far (example text provided because I'm pulling from a file):

```
import itertools

text = "This is a sample text for this example to work."
word_list = []
word_seq = []

text = text.strip()

for punc in ".,;:!?'-&[]()" + '"' + '/':
    text = text.replace(punc, "")

words = text.lower().split()

for word in words:
    word_count = len(word)
    word_list.append(word_count)

word_list.sort()

for key, iter in itertools.groupby(word_list):
    word_seq.append((key, len(list(iter))))
```

Comment: Try doing it with a simple 2d list (list of lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput

freq = {}
max_freq = 0

for line in fileinput.input():
    length = len(line)
    freq[length] = freq.get(length, 0) + 1
    if freq[length] > max_freq:
        max_freq = freq[length]

for i in range(max_freq, -1, -1):
    for length in sorted(freq.keys()):
        if freq[length] >= i:
            print('#', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end='')
    print('')
```

Comment: How do you print the axes with numerical values though?